# eclipse project facet osgi.bundle could not be found

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, osgi

I've installed Eclipse Kepler Java EE, and added an OSGi Bundle Facet from the update site.

I'm trying to test this Blog example from tutorial http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/topic/com.ibm.aries.osgi.doc/samples/blog/blogExamples.html on a Bluemix cloud.

When I go to blog's persistence project properties > Project Facets, I can see this warning:
"Implementation of version 1.0 of project facet osgi.bundle could not be found. Functionality will be limited"

Does anyone knows if the deployment fails for osgi plugin could belong to this warning ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the PDE tools to Eclipse, they have most of the OSGi support.

Comment: Hi Tassos, thanks for your answer.
My Eclipse environment works fine, I just want to know if there a way to made Bluemix cloud runtime (Java Liberty) working with existing OSGi plugins.

Comment: Ah, but that isn't what you asked in the original question, is it? I'd suggest writing a new one. Also, the "functionality will be limited" applies to the tooling within Eclipse, not to the deployment.